# literal does not match format string-version 11

Tags: sql, oracle

In my SQL query I have,

```
TO_DATE('2019-07-22' , 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

I want to pass `sysdate-1` instead of hard coding the date value.

I tried this,

```
select TO_CHAR(to_date(
sysdate-1,'DD-Mon-YY'),'YYYY-MM-DD')dates from dual
```

and replaced the same in the SQL query but am getting the below error,

> ORA-01861: literal does not match format string
>   01861. 00000 -  "literal does not match format string"
>   *Cause:    Literals in the input must be the same length as literals in
>              the format string (with the exception of leading whitespace).  If the
>              "FX" modifier has been toggled on, the literal must match exactly,
>              with no extra whitespace.
>   *Action:   Correct the format string to match the literal.

Comment: Replace the entire thing simply with `sysdate - 1`. No need for any `to_date`, `to_char`, or any format models.

Comment: **NEVER**, ever call `to_date()` on a value that is already a date (which `sysdate` is). That will first convert the `date` value to a `varchar` just to convert that `varchar` back to a `date` which it was to begin with.

Comment: @Winnieg You'd probably want to use `trunc(sysdate)` etc, rather than just `sysdate` (unless the you want the time to be used as well)

Answer (score 0):

Sysdate is a function that returns `DATE` datatype; you don't `TO_DATE` it. Therefore:

```
SQL> select to_char(sysdate - 1, 'yyyy-mm-dd') result from dual;

RESULT
----------
2019-08-01

SQL>
```

---

If you meant to use date datatype, then - as comments suggest - there's no need for any TO_something function:

```
SQL> select sysdate as today,
  2         sysdate - 1 as yesterday
  3  from dual;

TODAY    YESTERDA
-------- --------
02.08.19 01.08.19

SQL>
```

The result of such a subtraction is `date` datatype. The way it is presented to you depends on NLS settings; in my database, it is set to `dd.mm.yy`. In order to *present* it differently, you'd either modify settings or apply `to_char` with appropriate format mask, e.g.

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'yyyy-mm-dd';

Session altered.

SQL> select sysdate as today,
  2         sysdate - 1 as yesterday
  3  from dual;

TODAY      YESTERDAY
---------- ----------
2019-08-02 2019-08-01

SQL>
```

Comment: Not even that. The original code has `TO_DATE(...., ....)` - a `date` expression. The equivalent using `sysdate` is simply `sysdate - 1`, no need to wrap that within `to_char()` (which will return a different data type than what the OP had in the existing code).

Comment: Well, yes, @mathguy - if `date` datatype was meant to be used afterwards. I presumed that they wanted to "see" what was yesterday's date, using desired format mask. I've added some more text to the answer, @Winnie - have a look.

Answer (score 0):

Although `sysdate` is a `date` data type, Oracle still stores a time component.

Your code (attempts to) remove the time component.  For this, use `trunc()`:

```
select trunc(sydate - 1)
```

or

```
select trunc(sysdate - interval '1' day)
```

Note that the time component is often now shown when you select the data and look at it.

Comment: @Winnieg . . . The code above definitely works (https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=d4fe31f79db725fb95c361547710d083).  What are you "passing into"?  The error is probably somewhere else.